# Intellij sbt: This symbol is required by ' <none>'

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to build my project with sbt after I have restructured some packages. I get the following error:

```
[error] Symbol 'term not.of.interest.loginMethod' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by ' <none>'.
[error] Make sure that term loginMethod is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of not.of.interest.
```

The weird part obviously is `This symbol is required by ' <none>'`.

Before the restructuring, the building worked without problems. 
I am using IntelliJ 2018.2.3 Ultimate, sbt plugin 1.8.0

Neither clean/compile, nor sbt project import or IntelliJ's Invalidate Cache/Restart function have helped so far. Any advice?

**Edit:**

I fixed the issue.
The problem was, that I renamed the package from "login**M**ethod" to "login**m**ethod", but did not rename the packaged object. Thats when intellij seems to get trouble resolving definitions.
I reverted the name to the camel case version and the project can now be built again as usual.

Maybe some scala-jon-skeet can explain the problem in depth - i dont know enough about the resolving of imports.

Comment: What sort of restructuring have you done?

Comment: Moved the respective package from one place to another within the src folder.